# Retag request: [case] <--> [computer-case]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request

The tags [case](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/case) and [computer-case](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-case) look like they are duplicates of each others.

Which one should we keep? Or are there any more specific uses to [case](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/case)?

Answer (score 2):

**I** think we should keep [case](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/case). More generic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep [computer-case](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-case). More specific.